# How to produce and consume rest service using jersey via application/octet_stream?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, bson, jersey-client

Firstly, I need to produce rest service for sending a POJO class include byte array field for image and other POJO class. Also need to consume this service using jersey client.It is possible to achive these using application/octet-stream MediaType. I already did it for only image file and it is working.
What is the correct way to do this?

```
    public class Sample{
        int               sampleId;
        Byte[]            image;
        Foo               foo;

       //constructor
       //getter setter
    }
```

---

```
    public class GetDataImage {

        @GET
        @Path("/gets")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        public Response getFile(@QueryParam("id") String id ) throws IOException {

            File file = new 
            File("..\test_image.jpg");
            RenderedImage image2 = ImageIO.read(file);

            Foo foo = new Foo();
            Sample sample = new Sample (1, new Byte[] {},foo  );

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new BsonFactory());
            mapper.writeValue(baos, responseChipoutImage);

               StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
                  @Override
                  public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException {
                    try {
                     // ImageIO.write(image2, "jpg", output);
                        new ObjectOutputStream(output).writeObject(responseChipoutImage);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
                };

                    return Response.ok(stream, "application/octet-stream") 
                            .header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = " + image2.toString())
                            .build();
                    }
}
```

---

This is the client:

```
public class Client {

    private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8090/Test/gets";

    public Client () throws IOException {

        try {
            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource objWebResource = client.resource(BASE_URI);
            ClientResponse response = objWebResource.path("/").queryParam("id", "1")
                            .type(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).get(ClientResponse.class);

            System.out.println("response : " + response);
            if (response.getStatus() == Status.OK.getStatusCode() && response.hasEntity()) {

            ResponseSample responseSample = response.getEntity(ResponseSample.class);

//          InputStream input = (InputStream)response.getEntity(InputStream.class);
//          BufferedImage bf = ImageIO.read(input);
//          File outputfile = new File("../test.jpeg");
//          ImageIO.write(bf, "jpg", outputfile);           

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new BsonFactory());
            // deserialize data
     }
        } catch (UniformInterfaceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientHandlerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        new Client();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution finally. The solution is hidden in Jackson JSON parser --> **Bson4jackson**.

changed server side *StreamingOutput* ovveride method like this :

```
StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
              @Override
              public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException {
                try {      
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new BsonFactory());
                mapper.writeValue(output, responseChipoutImage);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            };
```

---

and then catched the data from client adding jackson bson parser from *InputStream*.

```
public class Client {
private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8090/Test/gets";

public Client() throws IOException {

    try {
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource objWebResource = client.resource(BASE_URI);
        ClientResponse response = objWebResource.path("/").queryParam("id", "1")
            .type(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).get(ClientResponse.class);
        if (response.getStatus() == Status.OK.getStatusCode() && response.hasEntity()) {

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new BsonFactory()).configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            ResponseSample responseSample = mapper.readValue(response.getEntityInputStream(), ResponseSample.class);
        }
    } catch (UniformInterfaceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientHandlerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public static void main(String...args) throws IOException {
    new Client();
}
```